# fortran type member array depending on type integer

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I would like to define a type in Fortran which has an integer member and an array member depending on that integer.

```
program example
IMPLICIT NONE
type m
    integer :: mSize = 2
    double precision, dimension(mSize) :: mArray
end type m

type(m) :: test
!do stuff 
end program
```

I do not want to use modules (yes, I know I am wasting memory!), since getting f2py and modules working together has not worked out for me (well, technically that is what I am doing, but it means in order to hide the module from f2py I have a subroutine which basically takes data and passes it without working on it and I am getting tired of the additional overhead, so I would like to work around this by including a type from an additional file)

Oh, and the bove code does not compile, gfortran complains that msize has no implicit type.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this in Fortran 90.  In Fortran 2003 you can define constructors so that your `allocatable` array as class member gets allocated with the given size.

Comment: In Fortran 2003 you can also have parametrized derived types.

Comment: Do you have to change the value at run-time? Do you need more types with different value defined at the same time? Or do you want one types, but instances with different values at the same time? This all affects the best design choice. The parametrized derived types are not yet supported by gfortran and will not be supported in the near future.

Comment: Do you need more types with different value defined at the same time?
->That is what I currently use ||

Or do you want one types, but instances with different values at the same time?
->this is essentially what I want ||

Parametrized types would solve my problem nicely, but as you stated, currently unavailable in gfortran and licensing intel or pgi is not an option. Anyway, thx for the input anyway.